# Permutation & Combination Doubt!

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Given the letters A, A, B, B, C, D, E. How many different arrangements are possible that begins and ends with the letter "A"?

I don't understand "user99680"'s explanation for arranging the two Bs in "5C2" ways.

He said "you can select 2 places for the B′s in 5C2 ways (with $_5C_2=\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$)."

Comment: What don't you understand about it? The number that was calculated?

Comment: If you don't understand an answer that a user gives you, you should ask that user to clarify, rather than make a new question.

Comment: @CameronBuie The OP has not enough reputation to comment. I can see nothing wrong with doing what they have done.

Comment: @user1729PhD: The OP doesn't have enough reputation to comment on *other people's posts*, but can comment on (answers to) his/her own. If you check the original post, you'll see that the OP has already commented on the answer there.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ah, okay, I understand. That said, the answerer in question did stop responding. So I think that this thread would be fine *if it had been posted a wee bit later*. Such as 24 hours after the initial post, or after the answerer had logged in and off again without replying. Neither of which has happened..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the $A$ at beginning and end, you are left with $BBCDE$ to arrange. This can be done in
$$
\binom{5}{2, 1, 1, 1} = \frac{5!}{2!\,1!\,1!\,1!} = 60
$$
ways.

**Explanation:** Number the repeat letters, so they are different. You have to arrange 5 different letters, which gives $5!$. If you now erase the numbering on the $B$s, you see that you overcounted by $2!$ (the 2 $B$ you took as different are the same). The $1!$ for the non-repeats have a similar explanation, you "overcounted" their arrangements by $1!$.

Answer (score 3):

From $7$ slots (7 letters), we need to put an $A$ in the first and last slot. There are "two-choose-two}" $\left(_2C_2 = \binom 22 = 1\right)$ way to do this.

That leaves *five* slots remaining, two of which must be occupied by a $B$ (two B's for two slots): there are "five-choose-two" $\left(_5C_2 = \binom 52\right)$ ways to do this. The order in which the B's are placed into the two chosen slots doesn't matter, since "a $B$ is a $B$."

Then we have three slots and three letters that can be placed in those slots in $3!$ ways.

That gives us $\dbinom 52 \cdot 3! = \dfrac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac {5!}{2!} = 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 60\;$ different arrangements possible.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're confused about the use of "5C2" or ${5 \choose 2}$, consider this explanation. ${a \choose b}$ refers to the number of ways you can choose two objects from a set of five, without regard to their order.

You can think of this as happening in steps. First, you must choose the two objects. There are 5 choices for the first and 4 for the second, giving $5\cdot 4$ possibilities by the counting principle. Note that $5\cdot 4 = \frac{5!}{3!}$.

However, since order does not matter in these cases, we need to "divide out" the redundancies. This is the second step. Since each one of your selections has two orderings, it can be arranged in $2\cdot 1 = 2!$ ways. Hence, the number of ways to choose two objects from a set of five is ${ 5 \choose 2} = \frac{5!}{2!3!}$.